# When I use `:term bash` from inside vim, the resulting "file" doesn't have the right date and time. How can I fix this?

Tags: statusline

For example, I'm currently writing a file `<x>.py`, and the status bar correctly displays the date and time the file was opened.
[image: A vim terminal's status bar with the date of December 12th, 2022]

I run, `:term bash` to get a shell inside of vim and the status bar has a date of `31st of December 1969`.
(Please ignore that it is currently running the git_auto.sh script.)
[image: A vim terminal's status bar with the date of December 31st, 1969]

Why is this, or where should I look in my computer to investigate why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

That status bar is definitely not by default. So you must be using some kind of a plugin (or simply few lines of code in vimrc) that we don't know and you are not telling us.

However, I can easily guess that your plugin has a bug: it tries to get the file time but fails, as the terminal itself is not really a file. So it must be getting minus one as a result. But it still probably insists on printing the result anyway. And so we all see that minus one second before "the UNIX era" it was the 31st December of 1969. Pretty useful, isn't it?

What to do then? Well, watch the quality of code you're using/copying/writing etc.